# View Button, Text, boolean and string don't exist

Tags: android, css, reactjs, native, tsx

I don't understand what i am doing wrong here. View, Button, Text, boolean and string are not functioning it says it doesn't exist

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import Voice from "react-native-voice";

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f5fcff;
`
const ButtonRecord = styled.Button``;
const VoiceText = styled.Text`
  margin: 32px;
`;

const Voz = () => {
   const [isRecord, setIsRecord] = useState<boolean>(false);
   const [text, setText] = useState<string>("");
```

Comment: It should be `styled.view` and `styled.button` (lower case). Are you sure you're running this in TypeScript? You don't have to add the generics to the `useState` calls as they are inferred by the values you provide.

Comment: the lower case doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it was Native. The upper case version is correct. I am able to run this code in a sandbox without error.

Comment: Really? I don't understant then

Comment: Can you create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import any libraries you use in your react app.

```js
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
```